# pandas groupby resample leads to missing data

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data that is based on every 3 hours and I try to resample it by using

```
df = df.groupby(df.index.date).resample('1h').pad()
```

however it stops at the last data at 21:00 everyday and the last three hours are not there. How should I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`DataFrame.asfreq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html)

```
df.asfreq('H').groupby(df.index.date).resample('H').pad()
```